# How to change font family for android floating action bar menu labels without writing custom style? (for android clans library)

Tags: android, button, floating, font-family, floating-action-button

I want to change font family of clans floating action bar menu labels. It says in changelog that this is implemented but i did not find how. I don't want custom style for label, just change fontFamily and keep original label settings. Is this possible?

Comment: can you please add a screenshot or image of what you are trying to change ?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
So, for these 4 menu labels i want to change fontFamily

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lzEFQYnwte2NHu10NZfnYMZMX8F0AkfI